# Unable to add data in a datatable asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datatable, row

```
DataRow new_row = tb11.NewRow();

 for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
 {
    new_row[i] = tb11.Rows[0][i].ToString();
 }

 tb11.Rows.Add(new_row);
```

I am running the following code to add data to a existing datatable but no data is inserted into the databale.

Comment: I dont see any problem in your code. Although you are adding the first row itself to the datatable, still, if there is data in the datatable it should reflect else it will throw a "No row at position 0" exception. Did you tried with tb11.Rows.Count before and after adding the row to be sure that no data is getting added? Also are you running in debug mode? If not and if there is a try..catch block then exceptions will not pop if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = ds3.Tables["FormName"];
dt.Columns.Add();
dt.Columns.Add();
dt.Columns.Add();
dt.Columns[2].ColumnName = "EmpId";
dt.Columns[3].ColumnName = "EmpName";
dt.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Branch";
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
dt.Rows[i]["EmpId"] = UID;
dt.Rows[i]["EmpName"] = EmpName;
dt.Rows[i]["Branch"] = Zone;
}
dt.AcceptChanges();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
string NEmpId = dt.Rows[j]["EmpId"].ToString();
string NEmpName = dt.Rows[j]["EmpName"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `newrow()` on the same table `tb11` from where you get your source data and adding new row in same table `tb11`. Also `tb11.Rows[0]` will access first row everytime